# SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler doesn't work if URL is opened from MS Excel

Tags: spring-saml

I've got a working `SAML` integration with `Azure AD` and `Spring Security/Spring Security SAML`. The URLs are like `https://<server>/report/123` and Spring Security nicely redirects to it after successful authentication through SAML.

The problem is when my users click in the URL through MS Excel - the saved request doesn't work anymore. I've found the MS Office starts with a `HTTP OPTIONS` on the 'directory' opened and excluded the requested URL for options from the Spring Security http element trying to avoid any interference:

```
<security:http pattern="/reports/.*/" path-type="regex" security="none" />

<security:http pattern="/reports/.*/.*" authentication-manager-ref="samlAuthenticationManager" path-type="regex">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="**" access="ROLE_ACCESS_REPORTS_URL"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/loginReports" login-processing-url="/reports/login"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="reportsSecurityExceptionTranslationHandler"
                authentication-details-source-ref="authenticationDetailsSource"/>
    <security:remember-me key="xxx" services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
</security:http>
```

Still no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe useful for some (the `HTTP OPTIONS` had nothing to do with it):

1. MS Excel (not the browser) opens the correct URL with user agent containing "ms-office". It gets a redirect to the login page
2. MS Excel opens the login page in the browser. Any information about the requested URL is lost at this point
3. Login process
4. ...

Inspired by https://serverfault.com/questions/588604/office-for-mac-hyperlinks-that-redirect-to-https-fail-to-load-with-unable-to-op, adding a redirect rule in nginx which always returns 200 if the user-agent contains 'ms-office'. It's a hack but works as Office is now opening the requested URL in the browser and the browser gets the appropriate redirects.